# GitLab: How to describe or tag a pipeline run, so that it's obvious from the UI, which environment it deploys to?

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, cicd

The pipeline deploys to the **staging** environment as a *merge request pipeline*, and to the **production** environment as a *branch pipeline* targeting the default branch (`master`).

While it's possible to infer the pipeline type (and target branch) from the UI to determine the deployment environment, I would like it to be readily availble as a pipeline description and/or a tag, like `latest` from the screenshots below.

How can I show the deployment environment to users, so that they don't have to decipher it themselves?

Example:

Merge request pipeline deploying to staging environment (visible from the symbol next to the pipeline ID) :

[image]

Branch pipeline for default branch (`master`) deploying to production environment (visible from the symbol next to the pipeline ID):

[image]

Comment: When you say environment here are you refering to gitlabs environments pipeline keyword? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#environment

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Could be, but also doesn't show up in the UI for easy reference. You need to click on a job to see its environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly see from the pipelines list perspective, but you have options.

Solutions 1 and 2 can be mixed to gain both advantages.

## Solution 1 : have different job names

With different job names you can have the information on the pipeline list by clicking on the deploy stage of any given pipeline, to see what is the name of the deployment job.

For that, your CI code should look like this :

```yaml
.deploy:
  script:
    - ./deploy.sh

 deploy prod:
  extends: [.deploy]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual

 deploy staging:
  extends: [.deploy]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
```

## Solution 2 : use GitLab environments

[environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/) concept in GitLab can be used for your current need.

GitLab does not have to know how you deploy, but with a few words in your CI yaml, it will take care of the rest (which is the latest job which deployed to this environment, which commit, author, the history, the ability to rollback to a previous deployment...).

Once the pipeline has started, you have immediate information that a deployment to an environment is in progress, in `Operate` > `Environments`.

You will gain the advantage to have CI variables with the exact same name but different values depending on the current environment.

Comment: Thank you, so one has to go into `Deployments > Environments` and select the different environments to infer where things are currently deployed? Say, you have three environments, this could be messy. Also, you can first see the pipeline environment target once the actual deploy jobs, with environment key added, start running?

Comment: I explained more and added another solution, does it fit you more ?